# How to redirect to view with two forms from an action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Action Method called `New` inside the controller called `Advert` and its view running well. I just needed to embed another form into the view for image upload:

```
<form action="/advert/ImageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is the Action Method for that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
{
    if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine("http://abcstorage.blob.core.windows.net/adv" + "_" + Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName));
            FileHelper.FileInsert(uploadfile, "adv", FileType.AdvertImage)
    }
        return View();
}
```

What should ImageUpload Method return? Apparently, not allowed to return view in this case. I just want the image to be uploaded and the keep going with the second form.

Comment: Is there a reason you need them separate? You can have a model and a file input control in the same method: `public ActionResult MyUpload(UploadModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)`

Comment: Before all form data submitted, image should be uploaded and displayed. I need two different submit button.

Comment: ok i get it. You can return a View from your method, but in this situation it's trying to return to a View called `ImageUpload` which doesn't exist. Use RedirectToAction("New") to redisplay the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "Controller",(optional new { actionParam=something, etc })   );
```

or you can

```
return View("ViewName");
```